# Running on runner-...-concurrent-0 via ... runner for LONG time never ends

Tags: docker, gitlab, digital-ocean, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use a custom docker container ..

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:8

# Install pngquant
...
# Install Python
...
# install yarn (via npm)
...
```

[image]

I follow [this instruction](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-centos-7) to install Docker on CentOS, [this one](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html) to install the runner and [this one](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html) to register the runner.

[image]

[image]

This is the configuration of my runner..

[image]

Comment: Which version of docker are you running?

Comment: docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:06:25 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:06:25 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false